# Replace deep level autowired dependencies with mockings in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

I have an complex object that I want to test. Lets call this object rest resource. This resource depends on a servie object, injected via @autowired and the service object has further dependencies, also injected via @autowired. I got my junit test class in the way I want with one single exception. The only problem I have is that I do not know how to replace a deep level dependency with a mocking.

There is @InjectMocks for example. That replace only direct dependencies, not nested. The other way could be via setters. The Problem is that the rest resource is not recreated for the next junit testcase. So if I change a certain dependency it will be used for the next test case.

I hope for someone who can help.

The code is like followed

```
@Controller
public class AccountCommandsController {

    @Autowired
    private LogoutService service;
}

@Service
public class LogoutService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    private HashService hashService;
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class AccountCommandsControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AccountCommandsController controller;
    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Mock
    private MailService mailService;
    @Mock
    private HashService hashService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        controller.getService().setMailService(mailService); //problem issue
        controller.getService().setHashService(hashService);
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }
}
```

To put it in the nutshell. I want junit to use the original dependencies (no mockings) except in certain junit test cases where certain dependencies should be replaced by certain mocking objects like mailService or hashService.

Edit:

Here is a test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class AccountCommandsControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AccountsRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private HashService hashService;

    @Mock
    private MailService mockedMailService;
    @Mock
    private HashService mockedHashService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void signupSuccess() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new AccountCommandsController(new LogoutService(repository, mockedMailService, hashService))).build();

        when(mockedMailService.sendSignupMail(any(RequestSignupMailEvent.class))).thenReturn(SignupMailEvent.mailSuccessfulSent());

        String email = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String pwd = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/signup").content(new Gson().toJson(new Account(email, pwd)))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        repository.acceptAny(a -> {
            assertNotNull(a.getCreated());
            assertNotNull(a.getModified());
            assertEquals(a.getEmailAddress(), email);
            assertEquals(a.getPassword(), pwd);
            assertNotNull(a.getVerificationHash());
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void signupVerificationSuccess() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new AccountCommandsController(new LogoutService(repository, mockedMailService, mockedHashService))).build();

        String hash = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        when(mockedMailService.sendSignupMail(any(RequestSignupMailEvent.class))).thenReturn(SignupMailEvent.mailSuccessfulSent());
        when(mockedHashService.getUniqueVerificationHash()).thenReturn(hash);

        String email = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String pwd = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/signup")
                .content(new Gson().toJson(new Account(email, pwd)))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        repository.acceptAny(a -> {
            assertNotNull(a.getModified());
            assertFalse(a.isVerified());
            assertEquals(a.getVerificationHash(), hash);
        });

        mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/signup/verification/" + hash)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        repository.acceptAny(a -> {
            assertNotNull(a.getModified());
            assertTrue(a.isVerified());
            assertNull(a.getVerificationHash());
        });
    }
}
```

I found a workaround. I use either

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new AccountCommandsController(new LogoutService(repository, mockedMailService, hashService))).build();
```

or

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new AccountCommandsController(new LogoutService(repository, mockedMailService, mockedHashService))).build();
```

Its only suitable for small apps. Is there a better solutions for deep level mocking?

Comment: Which is your subject under test? It may help if you could show more of your test class. For example, if `controller` is a collaborator of the SUT, then why are you worrying about the controller's collaborators. To illustrate, if your testing class A and A depends on B and B depends on C ( A - B - C), it should not be necessary to provide C as you should be testing A's interaction with B only. If B exposes C to A, then that may suggest a design flaw.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. An more detailed example is absolut necessary. Is my new example more explainable? Furthermore its abolutly a design flaw if B show C to A. Its not in my case. My case is that my rest controller only forward to my service layer. It is not very advantageous if i test delegating only. So I want to test the whole chain of Rest->Service->SubServices

Comment: Actually, I disagree - for a unit test, if delegation is all that happens, then delegation is all you should test. What you are doing is a form of integration test. If you're interested Paractical Unit Testing is, in my opinion, a really good book (http://practicalunittesting.com/)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to create alternative versions of the spring.xml or application-context.xml configuration, just for testing. i.e. leveraging the Autowired capability, instead of Mockito, to inject the stubbed object.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to mock nestetd dependencies for example some service underneath you have to annotate it with @Mock annotiation, then later if some dependent service uses it you have to put @InjectMocks annotiation on it.

When Mockito will init mocks in setup method it will look that you provided mock implementations for the service and will inject them via @InjectMocks annotiation.